# How to Create MongoDB Atlas Search Index on a Nested String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to create an Autocomplete UI for my frontend. As a result I'm running the following query:

```
    return Product.find({ 'data.text': { '$regex': `${searchTerm}`, '$options': 'i' } }).limit(200);
```

Unfortunately, the above query is so so slow.

After digging around, I was advised to use MongoDb Atlas Search Index to speed up my queries.

My product schema is of the form

```
{
  ...,
  data: Object //Can contain any key value pair one of which is text as used above
}
```

Creating a regular Atlas Search Index has been straightforward like

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields":[
      "name":{
        type:"string"
     }
    ]
  }
}
```

But how can I create a nested Search Index for my above use case. I would like to index `'data.text'` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index on a nested field using:
`db.collection('...').ensureIndex("data.text": 1)`

Or

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields":[
      "data.text":{
        type:"string"
     }
    ]
  }
}
```